Omni magazine (maybe) about neo-primitives destroying the last bit of technology
I'm trying to identify a short story, possibly published on Omni magazine.
IIRC, the protagonists were flying in an airplane, using some sort of beam to irradiate the Earth below them, which caused all technology to crumble to dust. They land, the job complete, and set the airplane to self destruct ... but then one character sees that the other character is hiding a mechanical watch up his sleeve. There's a discussion because the guy with the watch wanted to save one nice thing form the old world, but it's agreed that to complete the process, they really do need to destroy everything.

Can't answer the question but if it's the story I'm thinking of - One of the pilots had altered the course of the plane so it avoided a cache of technology but was found out and it was destroyed. There was also a thought about future geologists finding metals in two forms - ore and pure veins - as the beam converted technology into its original materials

Got it - "St. Amy's Tale" by Orson Scott Card, Omni December 1980 - https://williamflew.com/omni27b.html

"three years wiping out everything east of the Mississippi, and I almost save a digital chronograph"


"Elouise was amused, thinking of the treatises that would someday be written about the two states of workable metals - the ore state and the pure-metal vein"


That's it!  Thanks!
